# Can 2 WCF service processes listen the same port?

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, tcp

I know 2 processes can't listen the same port, but [as it happens with HTTP requests in the port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067830/how-can-a-wcf-service-listen-the-same-port-as-iis), I know Windows can receive the packets and reroute to the appropriate services. I just don't know if it also happens with other ports and protocols (net.tcp for instance).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you run the WCF-provided [Net.Tcp Port Sharing service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734772.aspx), you can allow multiple WCF applications to listen on, and share, the same TCP port.