# Sharing ports with JBoss/tomcat and HTTP.sys?

Tags: wcf, http, tomcat, jboss

I am using JBoss 4.0.3 in a Windows environment.  I would like to share the same HTTP port between two applications (JBoss and a stand-alone WCF application).  HTTP.sys in Windows supports this (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067830/how-can-a-wcf-service-listen-the-same-port-as-iis/2068052#2068052)).

1. Is it possible to configure JBoss/Tomcat to only bind to specific URLs, instead of globally to the configured port?
2. Is it possible to configure JBoss/Tomcat to use HTTP.sys on Windows (effectively binding to specific URLs as in 1 above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.  Based on some research (aka, googling), I found this ancient discussion related to apache: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/dev/266393.

Also, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2010/11/07/adding-ssl-https-security-with-tomcat-java-solution-in-windows-azure.aspx), there is a vague reference tomcat not using it either:

> "Since Tomcat does not use http.sys internally..."