# Why does OS X allow listening on the same TCP port twice?

Tags: macos, sockets, netcat

I was trying to debug port allocation problems in Jenkins on OS X by listening to certain ports with netcat, which led to some weird results.

---

In a terminal on OS X 10.8.2:

```
$ uname -rs
Darwin 12.2.1

$ nc -l 54321
```

Then in an second terminal:

`$ nc -l 54321`

And in a third terminal, `lsof` shows that both instances have bound to the same port:

```
$ lsof -i | grep 54321
nc  70706 chris    3u  IPv4 0x55618c024692f4d1      0t0  TCP *:54321 (LISTEN)
nc  70769 chris    3u  IPv4 0x55618c0232cb8661      0t0  TCP *:54321 (LISTEN)
```

---

On Linux:

First terminal:

```
$ uname -rs
Linux 3.2.0-34-generic

$ nc -l 54321
```

Second terminal:

```
$ nc -l 54321
nc: Address already in use
```

---

Why doesn't OS X also report that the address is already in use?

Comment: I don't know the `lsof -i` output syntaxis, but what are `0x55618c024692f4d1` and `0x55618c0232cb8661`? If it are IP addresses, then it's obviously because the listener was bound to a specific IP address and not the "any" address.

Comment: They're meaningless memory addresses. The only purpose they have is to identify that these are two distinct sockets (e.g, not the result of a `fork()` or `dup()`).

Comment: Running `lsof -i` gives me 27 unique values for that field ("DEVICE"); I believe it's a memory address. The final column shows that the sockets are bound to `*`.

Comment: Of course, and they're too long to be IPv4 addresses anyway. I stand corrected. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The binary on OS X is setting the SO_REUSEPORT socket option, which allows completely duplicate bindings ([setsockopt on OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/setsockopt.2.html)). You can verify this using dtrace on OS X.

The netcat binary on Linux does not do this, so you get a bind error as expected. Again, you can verify that using strace. I belive SO_REUSEPORT is deprecated, or not even available on newer Linux kernels.

Comment: Thanks for the info! That also explains why if another piece of software was running, `nc` *did* complain that the port was already in use.

Comment: For info, the SO_REUSEPORT socket option was added to Linux 3.9: https://lwn.net/Articles/542629/

Comment: This is helpful however can you provide an example of `dtrace` which can help a programmer confirm this?  The examples I've found online are sparse and a bit hard to understand, especially if that programmer is unfamiliar with C.  This makes it harder to identify for those dealing with this issue downstream such as in an interpreted / JIT fashion.