# Is it possible to run two NIO server sockets on a single port?

Tags: java, sockets, nio

Is it possible to run two NIO Server sockets on a single port? I am using Apache MINA for server sockets. I am running a one server on port 8090 and simultaneously is it possible to run another server on the same port?

Comment: Apparently only if using UDP. See this thread for a starter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port

Comment: What is the point of doing this? If both servers do the same, then one sever is enough. If they behave different, how are you going to determine which connection goes to which server?

Comment: I want to use Jboss application server and socket server on a single port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not if they are both using TCP, unless they are both bound to different interfaces. What would be the point exactly? They would both just sit there accepting connections. One is as good as a thousand.

Comment: I dint get you. Could you please elaborate the answer.

Comment: @Rocky +1 The OS determines which service/ServerSort to use by IP address and port alone.  If you were to listen twice, the OS would have no way of knowing which service should be called.  Instead the application should listen once and decide which service should be used based on content, load balancing or source IP address.

Comment: @Rocky Which part of 'not' don't you understand? I've already asked you to elaborate your question. Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: I want to use Jboss application server and socket server on a single port. So I want to know whether it is possible or not