# Receive data by some processes

Tags: udp

Can I receive data from network by some processes simultaneously?

For instance, I have two computes in the LAN. One computer send udp packet to other computer on port 5200. In computer number two I want to receive this packet by two  processes. Can I create two sockets on same ip and port?

I forget to say that Process A I can't modify. In other words, I want to create application that receive same data as Process A. (Proccess A and Proccess B locate on the computer number two that receive data)

Comment: Privet Oleg :-) I have a edited my answer below, check it to find the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! You can. Open the socket and set setsockopt with REUSE_PORT and REUSE_ADDRESS.

Answer (score 1):

How about you create **process A** to act as middleware between the two **processes B** and **C**. And then add extra data to the packets sent to **process A** which will be used to determine the final destination of the data - **process B** or **process C**.

**EDIT:**
To answer your question exactly "no", for TCP/IP

> "You can only have one application listening on a single port at one time."

Actually you question has been asked by someone else before, and I have only just cited the answer. The full answer can be found -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port).