# Run multiple services which control port

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have a windows service which listens for TCP messages, responses to them and then saves information to a database. Overall the CPU and memory usage is relatively small.

I would like to run multiple of these on a single machine however the problem is that the only way I know which service is by the destination IP. Thus is it possible for multiple to run on a single machine?

**Update:** I need them to all run on the same port. Thus service1 and service2 both listen on port X. A message intended for service1 must not go to service2. The messages themselves are indistinguishable. The only way the message knows it is going to service1 is the destination ip.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? You can install multiple instances of the same exe as different *service names* in windows, and then lookup the requested service-name at runtime. Is that what you mean? Presumably you would then have some configuration settings per-service-name, and configure a different port number per service-name...?

Answer (score 0):

I guess port was originally designed to be some type of “service ID”, if this is completely inappropriate, you should consider additional logic inside your service for load balancing. Or something else...

[Can two applications listen to the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port)