# How is it possible for two applications to listen on one port?

Tags: c++, networking, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I'm writing several apps which communicate with network using Boost.ASIO. Suddenly two of them got the same port in config due to the mistake and both of them successfully started listening on the same port. Here is from `netstat -na` output

> TCP    0.0.0.0:40000          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
>    TCP  0.0.0.0:40000          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

How can it be so? Two different apps are using one and the same TCP port!

Comment: You can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port

Comment: As you see, both are TCP, not UDP. I expected that second app would get an exception but it successfully started listening.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible if the socket was opened with the flag [SO_REUSEADDR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows.  Unfortunately, the SO_REUSEADDR flag has different semantics on Windows than on *nix, which allows this behaviour.

If you're worried that another app may try to listen on the port you are using, you can use the SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE flag.  If you are in control of all the apps opening sockets, then make sure you are not using the SO_REUSEADDR flag.