# How to have more processes listen on the same port of the same machine with QUdpSocket::ShareAddress?

Tags: qt, sockets, udp, localhost

I'm on Linux with QT 4.8.

I would like that 2 or more processes on the same machine could listen on the same port for UDP datagrams. Qt documentation says that QUdpSocket::ShareAddress can do that.

I have implemented 2 receivers with this code:

```
connect(&rec, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(leggiDati()));
rec.bind(QHostAddress::any, 5000, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
```

the "leggiDati()" function:

```
while(rec.hasPendingDatagrams()){
  QByteArray dato;
  dato.resize(rec.pendingDatagramSize());
  rec.readDatagram(dato.data(), dato.size(), &sender, & port);
}
```

and the sender code:

```
QUdpSocket send;
QByteArray dato = "prova invio";
send.writeDatagram(dato.data(), dato.size(), QHostAddress::LocalHost, 5000);
```

With the previous code, only the last process started receives the datagram. if I send a broadcast datagram, instead of on localhost, both processes receive the message.

can anyone explain to me why this happens?
Is there any way to permit communications on localhost avoiding to send broadcast messages?

Comment: now, I succeed in getting datagram in both processes thanks to 127.255.255.255. Sender sends datagram to 127.255.255.255 so both receivers can get the same message. Is there any contraindication for this?

Answer (score 1):

This comes down to understanding how sockets bind to a port.  So you're experiencing the expected behavior.

[Can two applications listen to the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port)

With regards to multicast UDP, I have never figured out the correct socket options to allow this to work with the QtNetwork module.  If I really needed to stick with Qt for this functionality I'd create my own socket and use setSocketDescriptor().  But instead I usually resort to the [ACE C++ library](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) for anything ***multicast*** UDP related.