# Multicast listening on same host and port in C

Tags: c, sockets, port, multicast

I have a program that listens for multicasts and I'd like it to be able to share a port with other instances of the same program, so that if I have 3 instances running on the same host, they can all share the same port.

Is it possible to do this, would it involve setsockopt and SO_REUSEADDR?

EDIT: I am going off of  [this site](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~claypool/courses/4514-B99/samples/multicast.c) for my code, the only thing I've changed is what is sent in the message.

Comment: Sounds similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port

Comment: @Santa That is much more information than I could hope to google on my own, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

setsockopt was what I needed, here is an example of what I did:

in the declarations:

```
int yes = 1;
```

then before the call to `bind()` i called `setsockopt()`

```
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes));
```

this now allows me to run multiple instances of the program on the same machine, listening for multicasts on the same port.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Mutlicasts are sent to an IP:port just like anything else. You won't receive multicasts sent to a different port.