# bi-directional socket to tcp communication

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, serial-port, socat

I have a software X listening and writing to TCP port. I.e. It creates a Server Socket and a client that reads and writes to TCP.

And I have a serial device ttyUSB0 which can accept data in a format that provides software X and send data back to serial.

I want to feed data from serial to TCP and vice versa, so that it looked transparent to software X and to a serial ttyUSB0.

I was trying to use socat. Like,

```
 socat -d -d -d -d -x TCP-LISTEN:7758,fork,reuseaddr FILE:/dev/ttyUSB0,b9600,raw
```

But it seems that it does not work. Looks as if listener on TCP port blocks binding. I have

> E bind(3, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:7758}, 16): Address already in use

Could someone please help me with my problem?

Comment: The address is already in use. Try another port.

Comment: @EJP I would though I have described my problem quite clear.

I'll make it simpler:

Software A listens and writes to port x.
Software B listens and writes to serial y.
I tried to bind x <-> y using socat.

I know that A occupies x.
That knowledge does not help me solve my problem.

Comment: But why are you trying to bind two sockets to the same port? It doesn't make sense. Bind the listening socket, then *connect* the other socket to that port.

Comment: @EJP My purpose is in description. My implementation most probably is incorrect. But I am not following your point either. First of all, I have 3 listening sockets. Which one are you referring to? bi-directional mapping means both sockets listen and write. And I have socat as a broker: A <-> x <-> socat <-> y <-> B

So, what do you suggest me to do then, given A(x), B(y) and socat?

Comment: You are trying to bind two sockets to the same port. Somewhere. Don't. It doesn't work.

Comment: @EJP Good day, sir. I'm afraid, I have issues with what to do, and not with what to avoid of doing. But thank you for your sincere advice.

Comment: 'What to do' is to remove one of the binds. You can't have both `socat` and your own software listening to the same port.

Comment: @EJP Unfortunately for me, that would mean that you do not know how to help in my situation. Because removing something per se would not help me to accomplish what I want.

Thank you for your effort.

Comment: You can't accomplish whatever it is you want to do by attempting  operations which you have already discovered to be impossible. Nor by simply ignoring what you're being told here. I suggest you make an effort to distinguish between your problem and your attempted solution. At the moment this has all the hallmarks of an XY problem.

Comment: What you want is simply not possible. 1 server = 1 port. 2 servers = 2 ports. You can connect any number of clients to one port, but you can only bind one server process.

Comment: @Damon My task was not to bind two sockets, but to make communication between software and device possible. Roland Bar below gave an answer that I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @EJP As I said before, I know that my attempted solution is wrong. If I knew what was wrong, I wouldn't ask. Fortunately, answer was found here. It was constructive and to the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As some commenters already mentioned, you can't make a TCP connection with two listeners. For a TCP connection you always need a server (listener) and a client.

As your software is already a server (listening on port 7758) socat should be run in client mode (connecting to your server).

This can be done with the option `TCP:<host>:<port>`, for example like this (adapted your example, not tested!):

```
socat -d -d -d -d -x TCP:localhost:7758 FILE:/dev/ttyUSB0,b9600,raw
```

Comment: This looks very promising and sounds clear to me. I'll try that later today.

Comment: Man, that worked great, you're awesome! I'll edit my question so that it should be more clear for everyone what I needed. I need to wait another hour before SO will allow me to award your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for TCP. Note that you could specify SO_REUSSEADDR but this will not cause BOTH listening applications to receive the data: only one app (decided at "random" by the OS) will receive the data, while the other will "hear" nothing.

If you can use multicast UDP you can do this.

See [Can two applications listen to the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port)