# nginx setup: connection interrupted

Tags: nginx

**Operating System:** Cent OS 6.4 64bit

I installed nginx on my server along with PHP and MySQL, I went through the configuration in the nginx config file, set my server name and listening on port 80.

However, I try to access the server by URL for the first time and I got the error

"The connection to * was interrupted."

Here is my config file from /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (Note: I already set the servername to a subdomain.)

```
    #
# The default server
#
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  *;

#charset koi8-r;

#access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}

error_page  404              /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    root           /usr.share/nginx/html;
#    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#    fastcgi_index  index.php;
#    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
#    include        fastcgi_params;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#    deny  all;
#}
```

}

Any ideas why? Or where can I start finding the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing.

---

You can't simply run Apache and Nginx on the same machine - both listening on port 80.

[Can two applications listen to the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port)

---

That message means there are issues establishing websocket connections. Check that you have properly configured nginx to allow websocket connections through.

```
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
```

---

Check your logs with

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log /var/log/nginx/error.log
```