# Using same port for two types of traffic

Tags: networking, port, mqtt

So we have a node [MQTT broker](https://github.com/mcollina/mosca) and a general node server.  We want to host them both on the same service as a single instance.  The default port for the MQTT protocol is 1883.  However, our hosting solution ([nodejitsu](https://www.nodejitsu.com/)) only allows external access through port 80.  We will also be running standard http traffic through port 80.

If we decided to stick with this nodejitsu and run both the MQTT broker and our regular server off port 80, are there any points of concern?  Or are there any benefits to running switching to a solution that allows other ports?

Comment: Turns out MQTT isn't even supported by nodejitsu because they will only accept http headers (MQTT is tcp).  Still interested in the question tho...

Comment: No, as this SO post explains:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port