# How to run sails.js application on port 80 with example?

Tags: node.js, apache, mod-proxy, sails.js

I have to put sails.js in port 80, but apache is already using it. How can I put both (sails.js and apache) on the same port 80? I need it because in my company all the ports are blocked except for PORT 80. (This is a realtime application with nodejs and socket.io (websockets) and in the other side a php application). Thanks a lot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port

Answer (score 5):

You have to run Sails on any free port (1337, for example) and use Apache with `mod_proxy`. Make sure it's loaded in Apache config, then your virtual host will be something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  www.youserver.com

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:1337/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:1337/
</VirtualHost>
```

See [`mod_proxy` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) for more details.

Comment: Upvoting this answer as it has specifics for working with apache (which is pre-existing)

Answer (score 3):

Put nginx in front of sailsjs, and dump apache, or make apache run on a different port.

DigitalOcean has a great tutorial on doing this with two nodejs apps.. You can find it [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-front-end-proxy-for-apache).

I also wrote a blog post about it [here](http://blog.gorelative.com/getting-sailsjs-and-ghost-to-play-nice-on-digitalocean-through-nginx/)

I do this on my server so i can run ghost blog, and sailsjs on the same server. This is how i have it setup.

```
NGINX Proxies blog.gorelative.com -> localhost:2368
NGINX Proxies gorelative.com -> localhost:1337
```

Just adapt the tutorial to proxy one domain to localhost:1337 for sailsjs, and add in the other hosts to host them normally.. or proxy the others to apache2, which probably is a waste of resources and not ideal.

**AFAIK:** With a bit more work your hosts don't even need to be on the same server. nginx can proxy to another server, and also do load balancing tasks.