# Using the original URL, not proxy, with browser-sync

Tags: proxy, localhost, gulp, browser-sync

Recently switched from Grunt.js to Gulp.js as multiple people told me how much better and faster it wa (it's true!). I have added [BrowserSync](http://browsersync.io) to my Gulpfile.js, making it easier to test on multiple devices. It works great and was simple to setup. For context, I develop WordPress sites for 95% of my working time, and run them on an Apache Virtual Host, with Multisite enabled, and have lots of local sub-domains set up for each client, e.g site1.domain.dev, site2.domain.dev, etc. This works great, and I have been doing it this way for a couple of years now. However, because BrowserSync needs to create a proxy to my site so it's able to sync and inject the CSS, the site currently running through BrowserSync is routed to `http://localhost:3000`. This is fine and I understand why it needs to happen, but it messes with WordPress a bit (as the URL isn't the same etc), plus I'm a big TypeKit/Cloud fonts user, which means that because the site is being routed through to localhost, none of the fonts are loaded. Of course, I could just add `http://localhost:3000` to the list of domains for each site on TypeKit, but this feels like a bit of a workaround and was wondering if there's a better way to do it.

I have added in the BrowserSync part of my Gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browserSync({
        proxy: 'site1.domain.dev'
    });

    gulp.watch('assets/styles/source/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('*.php', reload);
    gulp.watch('assets/js/source/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('assets/js/plugins/**/*.js', ['plugins']);
});
```

So my question is, **would it be possible for BrowserSync to go directly to my URL (http://site1.domain.dev) instead of routing it though `http://localhost:3000`**? As an added bonus, it would be awesome if the domain could be removed from the BrowserSync proxy property, as I use an automation script to set up a new site on my WP Multisite installation and don't really want to have to edit my gulpfile everytime I set up a new site.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: I cannot answer your bolded question, but as for the TypeKit part, add the option `xip: true` to your browser sync option and add `*.xip.io` to the TypeKit domains. See [1](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-xip) and [2](http://welchcanavan.com/developing-locally-with-typekit-and-xip/). As a workaround for the rest, it might be possible to use Nginx or something equal, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713016/).

Comment: I recommend https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/558

Answer (score 31):

For me, it worked by specifying `host` and then `open:` `'external'`, like this:

```
browserSync.init({
  proxy: 'http://myproject.dev/',
  host: 'myproject.dev',
  open: 'external'
});
```

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: Not  working for me... using:
browserSync.init({
  proxy: 'localhost/mysite',
  host: 'localhost',
  open: 'external'
});
still :3000 showing up in the address

Comment: @Selrond you can try with open: 'local'. This worked for me (i am doing development in a messed environment of laravel valet)

Comment: Works perfect for me! Set the `proxy` and `host` to the same url and it works like a charm!

Comment: I get the server at `myproject.dev:3000`. This is presumably because port 80 is already in use by the instance of Apache that is running.

Comment: what does 'external' mean?

Answer (score 19):

Check if it will help you. My gulpfile.js looks like this:

```js
gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
  browserSync({
    logPrefix: 'Your Project',
    host: 'site1.domain.dev',
    port: 3060,
    open: false,
    notify: false,
    ghost: false,

    // Change this property with files of your project
    // that you want to refresh the page on changes.
    files: [
      'public/css/**.min.css',
      'public/js/**.min.js',
      'app/**/*.php',
      'index.php',
      '.htaccess'
    ]
  });
});
```

After you run Gulp, the console will show a snippet of code that you need to put in your HTML before the `</body>`. The version of browser-sync-client and the port you are using may be different. Note: after you insert the snippet in your code, the message will still appear. From version 1.5.2 of BrowserSync, [you can disable the log snippet](https://browsersync.io/docs/options#option-logSnippet) with `logSnippet: false` in your configuration.

```
[Your Project] Copy the following snippet into your website, just before the closing </body> tag
<script type='text/javascript' id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[
    document.write("<script async src='http://HOST:3060/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.X.X.X.js'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
//]]></script>

[Your Project] Access URLs:
----------------------------------
UI: http://localhost:3060
----------------------------------
UI External: http://site1.domain.dev:3060
----------------------------------
[Your Project] Watching files...
```

After you insert the generated snippet in your file, save the file and open the address http://site1.domain.dev without port in your browser. If everything is correct, the site will update on changes from `browserSync.files`.

You can add a verification to only include this snippet in development environments. For example, I using PHP and CodeIgniter in my projects, so, to include only in development environments, I do this:

```php
<?php
if (ENVIRONMENT === 'development') {
    $browserSync = rtrim(base_url(), '/') . ':3060/';
    $fileHeaders = @get_headers($browserSync);

    if ($fileHeaders) { ?>
        <script id="__bs_script__">
            document.write("<script async src='http://HOST:3060/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.X.X.X.js'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
        </script>
    <?php }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 12):

Good question - I'm on WordPress too and had a similar issue. The documentation on the BrowserSync site doesn't really make this clear, but I came across a solution to my problem on the Overview page of the BrowserSync UI that runs at http://localhost:3001/. The message comes up when you run BrowserSync without a mode flag like `--proxy`.

If you paste this snippet somewhere before your closing `</body>` tag

```
<script type='text/javascript' id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[
    document.write("<script async src='http://HOST:3000/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.2.6.1.js'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
//]]></script>
```

and run BrowserSync without the `--proxy` flag, for example

```
browser-sync start  --files "css/*.css"
```

It will refresh your site at its normal address. I'm going to wrap the snippet in a condition so it only gets included on my dev environments - in the future maybe some kind person could write a LiveReload-style Chrome extension to do the job. Not sure if this fits your particular case with Gulp, but it works with command line.

Comment: I've tried inserting that script, but when I run browser-sync start it tells me to add the script. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks - this worked perfectly for me. @TylerPflueger you can just ignore that message to add the script. Now I just have to remember to take this out before deploying!

Answer (score 2):

Using [Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV) I follow the solutions already mentioned but I kept getting a `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when polling from Browser Sync, to solve that I did the following:

**gulpfile.js**

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

gulp.task("serve", () => {
    browserSync.init({
        socket: {
            domain: "localhost:3000"
        }
    });

    gulp.watch("**/*.php").on("change", browserSync.reload);
});
```

Running `gulp serve` on your terminal will log a snippet, from that snippet take the version of the browser-sync-client and replace it in:

**functions.php**

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_footer', function () { ?>
    <script type='text/javascript' id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[
        document.write("<script async src='http://localhost:3000/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.X.X.X.js'><\/script>");
    //]]></script>
<?php }, 999);

?>
```

Note that the host name of the script is the same as the socket domain `localhost:3000` and that at this point you should be able to enter from your domain name and have Browser Sync reloading your site when any php file is changed.

---

If you want to get rid of the snippet that Browser Sync logs:

```
browserSync.init({
    logSnippet: false,
    socket: {
        domain: "localhost:3000"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me, because when I deploy my app it needs to listen on all addresses by using `0.0.0.0:5000` - just like Heroku does. I use dokku, and open source option for a Heroku-like PaaS.

```
gulp.task('serve', () => {
  browserSync.init({
    port: process.env.PORT || 5000,
    server: { baseDir: root }, // you may not need this
    domain: '0.0.0.0'
 });
});
```

It still opens on `localhost:5000` when I run the `gulp` task, but as I usually only need gulp for development and not production this has been working fine for me.