# Enabling Browsersync UI on nginx

Tags: nginx, vagrant, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I use a Vagrant VM to reproduce my production server for local web development.

Host machine is running Windows 10 and guest runs Nginx 1.10 on Ubuntu 14.04 with VirtualBox as a provider.

I want to serve files during development using Gulp and Browsersync.
Here is my browsersync configuration from gulp serve task:

```js
browserSync.init({
  ui: {
    port: 3001
  },
  open: false,
  port: 3000,
  server: {
    baseDir: ['.tmp', 'app'],
    routes: {
      "/bower_components": "bower_components"
    }
  }
});
```

I managed to get it to work with this:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}

server {

    server_name test.local.dev;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    }

    location /ui/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
    }

    # BrowserSync websocket
    location /browser-sync/socket.io/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

}
```

Socket configuration as seen here: [How to make BrowserSync work with an nginx proxy server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713016/how-to-make-browsersync-work-with-an-nginx-proxy-server)

The site, reloads and browsersyncing works great. But UI can't find needed files.

```
GET http://test.local.dev/js/vendor/socket.js 
GET http://test.local.dev/js/app.min.js 
GET http://test.local.dev/js/pages-config.js 
GET http://test.local.dev/lib/client-js.js 
GET http://test.local.dev/js/vendor/socket.js 
GET http://test.local.dev/js/app.min.js 
GET http://test.local.dev/js/pages-config.js 
GET http://test.local.dev/lib/client-js.js 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I set up routes for those requests in Browsersync configuration? If it's impossible is there any way to make it work?

Comment: did you try to replace localhost by test.local.dev in your config ?

Comment: No, I didn't. I don't know which config you mean.
@FrédéricHenri

Comment: in your proxy conf http://localhost:3000 --> http://test.local.dev:3000

Comment: I tried that but nothing has changed. I think that if I could tell browsersync UI where to look for files all would be good.
I tried to set up proxy and socket instead of server in browserSync.init() but I don't understand them and required Nginx configuration.

Comment: add [`host`](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-host) in your browser sync.init() if `test.local.dev`
 does not work try the IP of the VM

Comment: It makes no difference. Served site works great on http://test.local.dev from any project but http://test.local.dev/ui looks for its files in server root with incorrect routing (as it seems).