# Apache Thrift same port bind by different processes

Tags: c#, sockets, thrift

I’m using Apache Thrift for interprocess communication and have 2 process listening on to different ports using the same service. But I would like to have this two processes bind to the same port. This way I would avoid sending the same message twice to different ports. 
When I configure with the same port Thrift I get this error:

> Error, could not listen on ServerTransport:
>   Thrift.Transport.TTransportException : Could not accept on listening
>   socket: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network
>   address/port) is normally permitted    at
>   Thrift.Transport.TServerSocket.Listen() in
>   d:\Thrift\trunk\lib\csharp\src\Transport\TServerSocket.cs:line 114
>   at Thrift.Server.TThreadPoolServer.Serve() in
>   d:\Thrift\trunk\lib\csharp\src\Server\TThreadPoolServer.cs:line 99

Is it possible with Apache Thrift? How can this be configured?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can two applications listen to the same port?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port)

Comment: That's not really related to Thrift. The issue is more fundamental.