# How to run multiple Laravel projects at same time?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

To run one laravel project we only need to type "php artisan serve". and it will be available on port 8000.

But sometimes we need to run multiple projects at the same time. How can we do this?

Comment: working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72018415/7186739

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**tl;dr** one cannot have more than one listener per `TCP` port at the same time. If you need more web server instances: try another port:

```
php artisan serve --port=8001
```

then go to http://localhost:8001

---

References:

- [Can two applications listen to the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port)
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x

Answer (score 2):

You can also run web server on multiple port in PHP application by the following command.

```
php -S localhost:8000 
php -S localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

First run your first laravel project blog as follows:
Open your command prompt and go to your drive where your laravel project exist.
And type php artisan serve

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\blog>php artisan serve
```

Now type http://localhost:8000 in browser and your blog project will run.

Again open another command prompt and again go to your another laravel project bloganother

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\bloganother>php artisan serve --port=8080
```

Now go to your browser and type http://localhost:8080 in your browser your another project will also run.

Answer (score 0):

1- First thing you need to mention port number in .env file.
**APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8001**
2- Run **php artisan serve --port=8001**

Answer (score -1):

Run first laravel project (with url: http://localhost:8000)

```
php artisan serve
```

Run another laravel project (with port specific url: http://localhost:8001)

```
php artisan serve --port=8001
```

Run one more laravel project (with port specific url: http://localhost:8002)

```
php artisan serve --port=8002
```