# How to run Multiple project of laravel 5 in one folder

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5, frameworks

I installed Laravel and run through php artisan serve.
It runs one project for one instance.
Like http://localhost/index.php

But I want to run multiple project on one instance of laravel
like : http://localhost/project_1_name/index.php
       http://localhost/project_2_name/index.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72043591/7186739

Answer (score 1):

In default, Laravel use the port 8000, so just change the port when you run the server in every project.
Exp:

> For first project:

```
php artisan serve
```

> In browser you access with:

```
localhost:8000/project1
```

> For second project:

```
php artisan serve --port=8050
```

> In browser you access with:

```
localhost:8050/project2
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can run multiple projects but with different ports. 
look into this link
[Multiple laravel projects at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817947/how-to-run-multiple-laravel-projects-at-same-time)

Answer (score 0):

You should install `valet`

easiest and minified web server to user

`composer global require laravel/valet`