# Xamarin says "Allow Multiple Bind To Same Port only allowed on Windows". What do I do?

Tags: c#, ios, sockets, xamarin, udp

I'm trying to use `SocketLite.PCL` with my iOS/Android solution in Xamarin,
but I get the message `Allow Multiple Bind To Same Port only allowed on Windows` when running it.

What does it mean and how do I fix it?

**EDIT:**
Example code I'm using can be found here: https://github.com/1iveowl/SocketLite.PCL

I put the following code inside `rotected async override void OnStart(){}` of the app:

```
var udpReceived = new UdpSocketReceiver();
await udpReceived.StartListeningAsync(4992, allowMultipleBindToSamePort: true);

var udpMessageSubscriber = udpReceived.ObservableMessages.Subscribe(
    msg =>
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Remote adrres: {msg.RemoteAddress}");
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Remote port: {msg.RemotePort}");

        var str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg.ByteData);
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Messsage: {str}");
    },
    ex =>
    {
    // Exceptions received here  
    }
);
```

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, so setting `allowMultipleBindToSamePort` to `false` stopped that error.

Now I get the error `Address already in use`.

However I am still curious as to what `allowMultipleBindToSamePort` is used for.

Comment: You should post the code where you use the library

Comment: @ganchito55 I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [new documentation](https://github.com/1iveowl/SocketLite):

> IMPORTANT: Please notice that the parameter allowMultipleBindToSamePort will only work on Windows. On other platforms it should be set to false

About *However I am still curious as to what allowMultipleBindToSamePort is used for.*

There is a good and complete explanation on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t/14388707#14388707), you can read more in the following [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port)