# Share port between Bokeh app and Flask app

Tags: flask, webserver, port, bokeh

I want to create a Flask app with embedded bokeh server document deployed on a web server.  Current bokeh [documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#userguide-embed-apps) demonstrates how to do this by running Flask on Port 8080 and the bokeh server on Port 5006.

In order to deploy on a very locked-down web server, I want **Flask and the bokeh server to share a port**, i.e. both use Port 8080.  Is that possible and if so what is required...

Comment: [You can't share TCP ports (which are used for web)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port). Widespread solution is to bind apache/nginx to 8080 and reverse-proxy with it to your apps.

Comment: The nginx configuration block [referenced in the documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#nginx) for this purpose has worked for my application of embedding a bokeh app in Flask.