# How to run django-rest-framework and react on the same domain?

Tags: node.js, redux, django-rest-framework, fetch, redux-thunk

Working on a website that uses `django-rest-framework` for the backend and `reactjs` + `redux` for the frontend.

Now my backend server is on a `vagrant` ubuntu machine on URL and port `http://localhost:8080`. Frontend using `react` + `redux` + `webpack(port 80)` + `cross-fetch` for API request/response, server is on `http://localhost`.

Facing two errors, when requesting an API using `cross-fetch` on `redux` for fetching data.

first error:

```
Failed to load http://localhost/courses-api/all-courses/: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Is it because of the different ports?

second error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Network request failed
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (browser-ponyfill.js:445)
```

Can not find out a way to solve the problem. Will using the same port for both solve my problem?. Found on the web for solving the first error, but can't do that as `nodejs` and `django` can not use the same port. When running one of them the other one cannot run on that port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I liked @a_k_v's answer: just one line in setting.py file.
also @NAVIN Introduced a great npm package.
But for production level ,  based on people's talking about it on stackoverflow, I insisted on having the same domain for both 'reactjs-webpack frontend' and 'django backend'. and here is my solution for that : I used nginx web server for handling both FrontEnd and BackEnd. by using UWSGI and a socket for django , and a Reverse proxy for webpack , I 
finally managed to run my server without any error.

my nginx configuration :

```
    server{
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com

        location /api {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix:/home/hamidk1373/uwsgi/pythontraining.sock;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
```

- I'm still in development mode using webpack-dev-server.

Comment: is this still working for ya?

Answer (score 0):

The first error because of cross-origin resource sharing. You need to configure cors in your server. To do so you need to install corsheaders and add it into INSTALLED_APPS. Then add this to your settings.py

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

Comment: thank you. this is a good solution for working on localhost. it resolved the error.

Answer (score 0):

No two application can run on same port at same machine. Ream more on this article [Can two applications listen to the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port)

For your first problem just use [cors.js NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) on backend and with `express.js` like:

`server.js` / `app.js`:

```
const CORS            = require('cors'),
      express         = require('express');

const app             = express();

// Cross-Origin Resource Sharing
app.use(CORS());
```

For your Second problem: There's a function returning back `promise` however is not handled properly from calling function or your `promise` is not been `resolved` or `rejected`.

Example JS:

```
function doSomethingAsync () {
    return new Promise ( (resolve, reject) => {
        // Just to simulate asynchronous functions using setTimeout()
        setTimeout( ()=> {
            // Doing asynchronous work like File read/write, database calls, API call, any other async.

            // If not resolve/reject function are not called then uncaught in promise error will come. Thus always call these functions.

           if('some condition is true') {
               resolve('Return success message here');
           } else {
               reject('Return your error here');
           }
        },10000);
    });
}

doSomethingAsync()
.then( result => {
    console.log('If promise resolved then here: ', result);
})
.catch( err => {
    console.log('If promise rejected then here: ', err);
});
```