# React Application Hosting same port

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to host the two different version (v1.0 and v1.1) of same React Application on Same Port(both version should run on 3000) of a linux server.
What changes i require in order to do deployment in such a manner .
I have created the react application with npm create-react-app.

Comment: You cannot have two application on the same port. Just change the port of one of them, and then configure your webserver to route correctly.

Answer (score 1):

[refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port), you will get an idea on ports... and it is not possible to do that

Answer (score 1):

Two applications cannot run on the same port.
Use nginx reverse proxy to redirect based on ports.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run 2 applications on same port. Alternatives are:

- Use nginx reverse proxy
- use Iframes to load 2 different applications and access them using routes