Using nodemon Server Listining on port: 4000 but finally [nodemon] app crashed
When I am trying to run the application, then the Server Listining & Database Connected Successfully but App is crashed directly.
Could not get any response at http://localhost:4000/
Here is the full error, nodemon version is 3.1.0
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server Listining on port: 4000
Database Connected Successfully
node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1872:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1920:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:2008:7)
    at Function.listen (D:server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635:24)
    at D:\server\server.js:25:13
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1899:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 4000
}

Node.js v20.9.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...


server.js full source code
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const connectDB = require('./db/db');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const obj = {
        name: 'jam',
        email: 'jam@j.com'
    }
    res.json(obj);
})

PORT = 4000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server Listining on port: ${PORT}`)
})

connectDB(`mongodb://localhost:27017/attendance-db`)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Database Connected Successfully');
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log(`Database Listining on port: ${PORT}`)
        })
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e))

package.json
{
  "name": "elb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "elb",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.3.5",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0"
  }
}

I changed the PORT several time but result is the same
Thank you for your time

Which package you are using in connectDB imported module? Is it mongoose or mongodb driver?The problem with the server.js is that you are using app.listen(..  twice in the scrip.please check and correct it in order to resolve the problem.

Its mongoose  [ const mongoose = require('mongoose')  ]

Okay,I have posted my answer.Please check and let me know.I believe it will resolve the issue.
Thanks.

answer given to your solutions

I have posted the full solution, please check it

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4000

It clearly means that you have already connected the PORT to 4000 and you are again trying to connect the same PORT.
You just need to remove a section of code from server.js that you have defined after PORT = 4000;
just remove it from server.js.The issue will be resolved.
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server Listining on port: ${PORT}`)
})

Remove only the mentioned code not the PORT where you assigned 4000 just before the above mentioned code.Try this.

Its a microservice, and need to run both,  so your reply is not correct, thank you for your answer

Got it. In this scenario you need to change the port. This may be helpful for you, check this .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75028501/how-to-run-different-server-on-same-port

Thanks for sharing good resource, its gives me a logical concept but I not get full solution

based on your given resource, I finally found the solution, and the full solution I posted

Here is solution
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const connectDB = require('./db/db');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const obj = {
        name: 'jam',
        email: 'jam@j.com'
    }
    res.json(obj);
})

PORT = 4000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server Listining on port: ${PORT}`)
})

connectDB(`mongodb://localhost:27017/attendance-db`)
    .then(() => {
        PORTDB = 4000;
        console.log('Database Connected Successfully');
        app.listen(PORTDB, () => {
            console.log(`Database Listining on port: ${PORTDB}`)
        })
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e))

