# when i run npm dev which is concurrently opens localhost 3000 which does not contain my project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, npm-scripts, concurrently

"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"server": "nodemon server ",
"client": "npm start --prefix client ",
"dev": "npx concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client""

This is the code on my server package json when I npm run dev it opens localhost 3000 which should have my frontend application but instead opens a new react app local host 3000

If I log into my frontend and run,it runs successfully on local host 3000 or sometimes claims that local host 3000 is occupied and changes the port number to local host 3001

I need For the npm run dev to open both client and server concurrently therefore opening the correct localhost 3000 which contains project interface

Comment: Could you share port setting for both client and server sides? My assumption is you are using the same 3000 port for both of them.

Comment: const PORT =process.env.PORT || 7809

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV}mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold));

Comment: Could you try changing the either ClientSide or ServerSide PORT to something else?

Comment: You can now view tracker in the browser.       

  Local:            http://localhost:3000      This is my client side port successfully opening on port 3000     Yes I did try changing the port number on the server side very hectic if you ask me I kept killing the ports and relaunching but the issue was still there

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to run both processes on the same PORT.Well it is not convenient to run two process on a single port concurrently you need to specify two distinct PORTs for each process.

Refer: [Can two applications listen to the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port)

Comment: thank you this really helped i figured out where the error was