# Unable to get data when using ip address as host in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, bluehost

I am using VS code to create a react js application.
I was able to get the data using this setup. I can see the results on my console log.

```
const db = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
  user     : 'myusername',
  password : 'mypassword',
  database: 'mydatabase',
  connectTimeout : 10000,
  port: 3306
})

app.listen(3306,()=>{
    let sqlInsert = "SELECT el.examID, el.categoryID, el.SubCategoryID, el.Question,A.A, A.B, A.C, A.D, A.Answer ";
    sqlInsert += " FROM ExamList el ";
    sqlInsert += " inner join ExamAnswer A on A.ExamID = el.ExamID ";
    sqlInsert += " inner join ExamSubCategory es on es.ID = el.SubCategoryID ";
    sqlInsert += " where el.CategoryID = 1 and es.ID = 1";
    db.query(sqlInsert,(err, result)=>{
        console.log(result);
    })
})
```

But when trying to get the data using app.get. My browser just keep on loading.
I tried http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/api/get

```
app.get("/api/get",(req,res)=>{
    let sqlInsert = "SELECT el.examID, el.categoryID, el.SubCategoryID, el.Question,A.A, A.B, A.C, A.D, A.Answer ";
    sqlInsert += " FROM ExamList el ";
    sqlInsert += " inner join ExamAnswer A on A.ExamID = el.ExamID ";
    sqlInsert += " inner join ExamSubCategory es on es.ID = el.SubCategoryID ";
    sqlInsert += " where el.CategoryID = 1 and es.ID = 1";
    db.query(sqlInsert,(err, result)=>{
        res.send(result)
    })
    });
```

I also tried https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/get and this is the error message
The connection for this site is not secure
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I am very new in react js and only relying on tutorials right now but I was able to build my application. And now I am facing this issue. I've been trying to solve this for 2 days now.
Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Well by default react dev server is using https protocol. And browser will block any resources (and requests) if page is in https and request resources are http. Next - get familiar with dev tools, browser's `Network` tab for example to examine requests and responses, status codes, etc, to figure out what exactly happened. 
Im not 100% if https to http requests is your the only issue, but here is the starting point for you: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Comment: Oh, next issue and question is why you have both `node app` and `mysql` using the same `port number 3306`? They should be different. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port